du -h only show folders but not files, how to show all?
I don't know what's going on with my centos 7 machine but seems like du -h /path only shows folders, not files, and it's annoying. I want to find all the files and folders at a specific depth and sort it by size.
For example (Note that even if I remove --max-depth=2 result is still the same)
[root@data-node12 ~]# du -h --max-depth=2 /root/quang/ | sort -rn
352M    /root/quang/
339M    /root/quang/test_folder

While I have many files inside /root/quang
[root@data-node12 ~]# ls -lh /root/quang/
total 14M
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  508 May 22 10:23 deleteClipLogByDate.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  68K Dec 22 14:01 extract.csv
-rwxr-xrwx 1 root root 4.7K Dec 21 17:38 goi_cuoc.sh
-rwxr-xrwx 1 root root 8.7K Dec 22 15:50 log_tuong_tac_kh.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   96 May 22 09:02 output_goi_cuoc.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   96 May 22 09:30 output_log_tuong_tac_kh.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May 22 10:53 test_folder
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  773 Dec 21 17:41 test.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14M May 22 10:54 trino-cli-435-executable.jar

also there is a file in /root/quang/testfolder
[root@data-node12 ~]# ls -lh /root/quang/test_folder/
total 339M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 339M May 22 10:53 fastmoney_vft.sql

Also please note that ls -lh command won't show the right disk space for folders, also can't sort, so that won't work.
How can I du -h and show all files and folders that I can sort (recursively if possible)? Is this some kind of bug?

du -a

If man du doesn't work for you, try info du.

There are several websites hosting manual pages, and the GNU documentation for coreutils, which du(1) is a part of.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Thanks. Can't biievie I miss that simple option

If you use du with a directory, it will by default calculate and show the disk usage for that directory and its subdirectories.  To also include files in the output, use du with its -a option (or --all if you are on a GNU system).  The -a option to du is a POSIX standard option.
Example:
$ du skel
16      skel

$ du -a skel
4       skel/.bashrc
4       skel/.zshrc
0       skel/.bash_profile
4       skel/.yashrc
16      skel

